# Could not resolve dependencies in maven on a Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: maven, dependencies, bitbucket, maven-3, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm getting the following error when a [Bitbucket Pipeline](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) is triggered:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gym: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project groupId:artifact:jar:4.14.0: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.2.1 -> com.google.zxing:core:jar:2.3.0: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.zxing:core:jar:2.3.0: Could not transfer artifact com.google.zxing:core:pom:2.3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
Connection reset -> [Help 1]
```

Seems like library `com.google.zxing:core` is not found on maven central repo, however it exists: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/2.3.0

When I try to collect dependencies from localhost using `mvn clean install` (same command defined on the pipeline) it works.

Any ideas?

**Updated**
When compiling on localhost I can see the following logs:

```
Downloading from yyy-maven-s3-release-repo: s3://yyy-
Downloading from yyy-maven-s3-release-repo: s3://my-custom-repository/release/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.pom
Downloading from jitpack.io: https://jitpack.io/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.pom (3.0 kB at 97 kB/s)
Downloading from yyy-maven-s3-release-repo: s3://xxx-repository/release/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.jar
Downloading from jitpack.io: https://jitpack.io/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.jar (529 kB at 3.9 MB/s)
```

For some reason it's downloaded twice.

On Bitbucket side the logs are the following ones:

```
Downloading: s3://my-custom-repository/release/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.pom
Downloading: https://jitpack.io/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.pom
Downloading: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.pom
Downloading: http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.pom
```

After that I can see:

```
Progress (1): 2.2/3.2 kB
Progress (1): 3.2 kB
```

But I have no idea if this lines refer to zxing dependency or to another one.

Comment: Check the URL that is being used to reported on resolved dependencies and make sure it is the same as when you run the ‘clean install’ locally.

Comment: @RichDuncan as you can see the urls are the same

Comment: It looks like the dependencies are resolving differently between the two environments.  Try running with --debug --errors to see if you can determine what the difference is (perhaps the settings.xml is different)